# .NET Async/Await for ODBC

Tags: mysql, .net, asynchronous, async-await

I've been looking into tuts about how to implement Async/Await. I already used it to read text files and process long loops and yeah it improved the responsiveness of my application.

What I'm looking for right now is how to use it in connecting to and getting data from a database.

I'm currently using ODBC to interact with MySQL. According to some tuts, functions like ExecuteNonQueryAsync is only available to SQLClient. If I'm not mistaken, I can't use SQLClient to interact with MySQL. Also tried using MySqlClient, I got nothing.

Did I miss anything or should I start thinking of another way? I'm open to other means.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there are async versions available yet (I.e. nobody has yet spent the time to write them).

Comment: I was afraid someone's gonna comment that. Thanks! Just had to confirm it.

Comment: Did you try MySQL's own [Connector/Net](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/)? The docs [list a full set of asynchronous methods](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-async-methods.html). The only problem is that it *fakes* asynchronous execution by running the command on a background thread. [MySQLConnector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/) is a *very* popular alternative, with 1.5M downloads

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I already got it running by using the usual BackgroundWorker style that I use. Thanks for the tip though. I'll look into that and see what else I can get.

Comment: @Coffeecat BGW is obsolete, fully replaced by Task.Run and `async/await` since 2012. It's particularly *un*suitable for data access where you typically need to perform multiple asynchronous actions one after the other

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I feel so old lol. Will definitely look into Task.Run and gradually replace my BGWs. My application is working perfectly with the BGWs though. Still, an update would be great! Thanks!